# finds the highest and lowest integers and then calculates the sum of the middle digits of those two numbers

Tags: java, intellij-idea

As the questions says... but here is a more practical example: Input: The generated numbers are: 175, 345, -567, 893, 100, -999,
Output: The maximum number is 893 and the minimum is -999. The sum of the middle digits of max and
mine is: 18

Basically the largest number 893 in this case, and the lowest -999 has a middle number of "9", 9+9 = 18
Im trying to understand how to pick out these two numbers (largest and smallest), but dont know how. I have done this:

```
public class Lab1_2 {
    public static void main (String [] args)  {
        int tal1 = (int)(Math.random() *899+100) ;
        int tal2 = (int)(Math.random() *899+100) ;
        int tal3 = (int)(Math.random() *899+100) ;
        int tal4 = (int)(Math.random() *899+100) ;
        int tal5 = (int)(Math.random() *899+100) ;
        int tal6 = (int)(Math.random() *899+100) ;

        System.out.println(tal1 +" ");
        System.out.println(tal2+" ");
        System.out.println(tal3 +" ");
        System.out.println(tal4+" ");
        System.out.println(tal5+" ");
        System.out.println(tal6+" ");

        if (tal1<tal2 && tal1<tal3 && tal1<tal4 && tal1<tal5 && tal1<tal6){
            System.out.println(tal1 + " is the smallest");
        }
        if (tal2<tal1 && tal1<tal3 && tal2<tal4 && tal2<tal5 && tal2<tal6){

            System.out.println(tal2 + " is the smallest");
        }
        if (tal3<tal2 && tal3<tal1 && tal3<tal4 && tal3<tal5 && tal3<tal6){
            System.out.println(tal3 + " is the smallest");
        }
        if (tal4<tal2 && tal4<tal3 && tal4<tal1 && tal4<tal5 && tal4<tal6){
            System.out.println(tal4 + " is the smallest");
        }
        if (tal5<tal2 && tal5<tal3 && tal5<tal4 && tal5<tal1 && tal5<tal6){
            System.out.println(tal5 + " is the smallest");
        }
        if (tal6<tal2 && tal6<tal3 && tal6<tal4 && tal6<tal5 && tal6<tal1){
            System.out.println(tal6 + " is the smallest");
        }


        if (tal1>tal2 && tal1>tal3 && tal1>tal4 && tal1>tal5 && tal1>tal6){
            System.out.println(tal1+" is the largest ");
        }
        if (tal2>tal1 && tal1>tal3 && tal2>tal4 && tal2>tal5 && tal2>tal6){
            System.out.println(tal2+" is the largest");
        }
        if (tal3>tal2 && tal3>tal1 && tal3>tal4 && tal3>tal5 && tal3>tal6){
            System.out.println(tal3+" is the largest ");
        }
        if (tal4>tal2 && tal4>tal3 && tal4>tal1 && tal4>tal5 && tal4>tal6){
            System.out.println(tal4+" is the largest");
        }
        if (tal5>tal2 && tal5>tal3 && tal5>tal4 && tal5>tal1 && tal5>tal6){
            System.out.println(tal5+" is the largest");
        }
        if (tal6>tal2 && tal6>tal3 && tal6>tal4 && tal6>tal5 && tal6>tal1){
            System.out.println(tal6+" is the largest" );

        }
    }}
```

I think I need to do something like this: but dont know how to implement to specifik largest and smallest.

```
int svar1 = (var1 % 100 / 10);
int svar2 = (var2 % 100 / 10);
```

Comment: You have several variable names that have the same names except the names end with different numbers. You then have several statements that are the same, except the names of the variables, previously mentioned.  This suggests you could have better code using loops and arrays.   Think about it. What if you had 1000 values for this task, instead of 6?

Comment: Use caution using the modulus (`%`) operator with negative values. One programming language might handle it one way, another a different way. The results are not always what the programmer expects.

Comment: Yes thats correct but I am not allowed to use loops or arrays

Comment: By the way, `(int)(Math.random() *899+100)` is not going to return a negative number.

Comment: Not allowed to use loops or arrays?  That's a surprise.  Even so, there is a way this can be done, even if you have to do  it for a lot of numbers. I don't want to tell you how too soon. Your professor probably wants you to think about it. Solving it will be a good lesson.

Comment: Okay thanks! How do I get negative number with random?

Comment: `(int)(Math.random() * n + m)`:  `n` is the number  of distinct values that can be generated; `m` is the minimum value.  So, `(int)(Math.random()*899+100)` will give you a random `int` from 100 to 998.   `Math.random()` returns a value from 0.0 to 1.0, inclusive of 0.0 but exclusive of 1.0.

Comment: By the way, Java offers a [Random Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Comment: You should edit the question to state that you are not allowed to use loops or arrays.  Also, will you always have 6 random numbers?  Or should  your code be able to handle a variable number of random numbers?

Answer (score 2):

first of all , the function `Math.random()` as mentioned in its description :

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

so it will never return a negative values , use `new Random().nextInt(2000) - 1000;` instead. this will generate numbers between **-1000** and **10000**

but I didn't edited that part of the code , because it's not clear what is the middle digit of the number **12** as in `new Random()` method , any number can be generated , so I left that for you to decide , for the part of getting max and min , also you said in the comments that loops aren't allowed , so I didn't modify that much in your code.

to get the middle digit , simply `(Math.abs(min) / 10) % 10 +  (Math.abs(max) / 10) % 10;` as `abs` function will make sure to remove negative sign and you do `(x / 10) % 10` to get the middle digit.

and here is the full code :

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main (String [] args)  {
        int tal1 = (int)(Math.random() *899+100) ;
        int tal2 = (int)(Math.random() *899+100) ;
        int tal3 = (int)(Math.random() *899+100) ;
        int tal4 = (int)(Math.random() *899+100) ;
        int tal5 = (int)(Math.random() *899+100) ;
        int tal6 = (int)(Math.random() *899+100) ;

        System.out.println(tal1 +" ");
        System.out.println(tal2+" ");
        System.out.println(tal3 +" ");
        System.out.println(tal4+" ");
        System.out.println(tal5+" ");
        System.out.println(tal6+" ");


        int min = tal1;
        int max = tal1;

        // gets the minimum
        if(min > tal2)
            min = tal2;
        if(min > tal3)
            min = tal3;
        if(min > tal4)
            min = tal3;
        if(min > tal5)
            min = tal3;
        if(min > tal6)
            min = tal3;

        //gets the max
        if(max < tal2)
            max = tal2;
        if(max < tal3)
            max = tal2;
        if(max < tal4)
            max = tal2;
        if(max < tal5)
            max = tal2;
        if(max < tal6)
            max = tal2;

        System.out.println("max = " + max);
        System.out.println("min = " + min);

        int sumOfMiddleDigits = (Math.abs(min) / 10) % 10 +  (Math.abs(max) / 10) % 10;
        System.out.println("sum of middle digits = " + sumOfMiddleDigits);
    }

}
```

and this is the output :

```
990 
676 
751 
653 
160 
307 
max = 990
min = 751
sum of middle digits = 14
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume there will always be a fixed number of generated numbers, and there will always be few. If the number of numbers is variable, or too many to have a separate variable for ech,  perhaps that should be addressed in another question.

The common way to find a maximum value of elements of an array is similar to this:

```
int[] arr; 
...
// code to new the array and put values into it
...
int max = -9999999;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
   if (arr[i] > max) max = arr [i];
}
```

The value `-9999999` is a value that is lower than any possible value in `arr`, and depends on the application.  But, if a possible value in `arr` could actually be the lowest value allowed for the data type, you could use this, assuming `arr` has at least one element:

```
int max = arr[0];
for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
   if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
}
```

But, what if your professor forbade the use of arrays and loops?

The general form of an `if` statement is `if (b) c` where `b` is a Boolean expression, and `c` is an imperative statement. An imperative statement is one that tells the program to *do something* -- take an action. It can be an assignment, a method call, exit, jump (such as a `GOTO` in old languages), and so on. It can be another `if` statement.

```
if (santaIsReal) System.out.println ("Ho, ho, ho!");
```

What if you wanted the program to do more than one thing? Well, Java allows you to put a block of code for `c`.  You group the statements by putting them between `{` and `}`:

```
if (today == christmas) { 
   santa.chimneySlide (myHouse);
   santa.leaveGift (bobby);
   santa.leaveGift (sue);
   santa.eatCookies ();
}
```

So, where you have code like this:

```
if (tal3<tal2 && tal3<tal1 && tal3<tal4 && tal3<tal5 && tal3<tal6){
        System.out.println(tal3 + " is the smallest");
}
```

You could add a line:

```
 if (tal3<tal2 && tal3<tal1 && tal3<tal4 && tal3<tal5 && tal3<tal6){
        theMin = tal3;
        System.out.println(tal3 + " is the smallest");
}
```

You would do something similar to find the maximum in the appropriate section of code.

Comment: You can remove the lines where you display the value of one of the `tal` variables with "is the smallest" or "is the largest."  Once you find the largest and smallest, display the values using your the variables for largest and smallest.

You could reduce the number of lines in your code by using methods in the [Math API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html):  `int min (int, int)` and `int max (int, int)`.

Suppose I want to find the maximum of 4 variables, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` using Math.max:

```
int theMax = Math.max (a, Math.max (b, Math.max (c, d)));
```

I infer you want to exclude single digit and double digit numbers from your randomly generated numbers.  A poor way, IMO, to do this is to try again when the result is in the "rejected" range. That would use a loop:

```
int myRand; 
do { 
     myRand = (int)(Math.random() * 2000 - 999 );
} while (myRand > 999 || (myRand >= -99 && myRand <= 99));
```

A better way is to generate two random values for each number:

```
int myRand = (int)(Math.random() * 1000 + 100);
if (Math.random()< 0.50) myRand = - myRand;
```

The code you have will get the middle digit of a 3 digit positive number:

`int svar1 = (var1 % 100 / 10);`

But, to be on the safe side, use `Math.abs (int)` to get it to work for both a positive value and a negative value:

```
int svar1 = (Math.abs(var1) % 100 / 10);
```